# access Spring MVC model from javascript / ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

After loading an html page and putting data in the model in the java code, I retrieve correctly the data from model using thymeleaf inlining: ((${data}))
When I do the same using an ajax requestthe data is null.
I also set a pediodic timer because of the asynchronuous call.
the data I want to get is 'manager'

```html
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    var myManager = [[${manager}]];
  alert("Interval reached every 5s " + myManager +  "  "+ [[${size}]]);
}, 10000);

function displayDetails(id,firstName,lastName,address,title,managerDatas,managedDatas) {
    $('.details').prop("disabled", true);
    
   document.getElementById("detailsTable").style.visibility = "visible";
   document.getElementById("saveEmployeeButtonId").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
   console.log("afficher Details");
   enable = !enable; 

   document.getElementById("detailledMatriculeDataLabelId").value = id;
   document.getElementById("detailledFirstNameDataLabelId").value = firstName;
   document.getElementById("detailledLastNameDataLabelId").value = lastName;
   document.getElementById("detailledAddressDataLabelId").value =  address;
   document.getElementById("detailledTitleDataLabelId").value =  title;
   if (managerDatas.includes(null)) {
        managerDatas='';
    }
    
    var mysize = [[${size}]];
    console.log("mysize " + mysize);
    
    id = parseInt(id);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/manager/'+ id ,
      
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {
            console.log('manager retrieve correctly');
            var myManager = [[${manager}]];
            console.log("manager1 " + myManager);

            console.log("manager2 " + myManager);
            document.getElementById("detailledManagerDataLabelId").value =  myManager[0];
        },
        error: function() {
           console.log ("manager ajax failed ");
        }
    });


   if (managedDatas.includes(null)) {
        managedDatas='';
    }
   document.getElementById("detailledManagedDataLabelId").value =  managedDatas;
   
    var myEmployee = [[${employees}]];
    console.log( 'msg1' + myEmployee[0].firstName);
   

}
```

```
  @GetMapping(path="/manager/{id}")
  public String  getManagedEmployees(Model model,@PathVariable int id) {
    List<String> employeeNames = employeesServices.findManager(id);
    StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
    
    for (String employeeName:employeeNames) {
        System.err.println("manager " +employeeName);
        String newEmployeeName = employeeName.replace(',',' ');
        strBuf.append(newEmployeeName );
    }
    System.err.println("strbuf " + strBuf);
    model.addAttribute("manager", strBuf.toString());
    return "/index";
}
```

Comment: You've got an "@" character in front of the Html.Raw 
that's what the error is complaining about. Can't tell much else from you example

Comment: Yes I saw some javascript with cshtml with this syntax. If it is not the good way, how to access model from javascript?

Comment: ... you'll need to show more of your js code. "CSHTML" would be part of a C# app, no? (not familiar with .Net, C#, hence asking). What are you trying to do here? Is it a simple hmtl/css/js page trying to call a Spring MVC controller? Is it a .Net app trying to talk to Spring MVC app?

Comment: No. I am well in java, javascript and  html. But I searching everywhere

Comment: ... there's a lot more info that we need to help you. What you posted is not enough. It looks to me like you copied and pasted some js and without a larger context no one will be able to assist you